# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'route'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. react-hooks/exhaustive-deps in NEXTJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

**HOW IS THIS AN ERROR IN yarn build but not on yarn dev?**

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router"

const route = useRouter();

useEffect(() => {
  if (user) {
    route.push("/")
  }
  else {
    console.log("login")
  }
}, [user]);
```

Comment: Likely dev is configured to warn, while build is configured to error.

Comment: Do you need help fixing the problem? If so - please clarify where you're getting stuck.